# redirect non www and http - NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect non-www urls to www within my Node JS / Express application.

The following snippet performs a 301 redirect successfully

```
function checkUrl(req, res, next) {
  let host = req.headers.host;
  if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect(301, "https://www." + host + req.url);
  }
}
```

I use it as so

```
app.all('*', checkUrl);
```

What it doesn't cover is `http` to `https`. I can do this in a function of it's own

```
function ensureSecure(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
    return next();
  }
  return res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
}
```

How can I combine the two so I can cover both scenarios

Comment: Why don't just add the two middleware in sequence?

Comment: I have tried that but redirects for non www are not enforced then

Comment: Have you created  a https server using ssl certificate?

Comment: Yes that's all in place

Comment: instead of app.all() with wildcard you can using app.use().

Comment: @Richlewis Also can you post the entire code please, atleast a minimum example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With express you can use `app.use` to run middleware on every request.

So combining what you've already achieved you get:

```
function checkUrl(req, res, next) {
  let host = req.headers.host;

  if (!host.match(/^www\..*/i))
  {
    return res.redirect(301, "https://www." + host + req.url);
  }
  else if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https')
  {
    return res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  }
  next();
}

app.use(checkUrl);
```

Comment: Joey you are a lifesaver, don't know why I couldn't figure that out